# How do you get the sum of two arrays while keeping track of carry (like bigInt in java)?

Tags: java, arrays, bigint

I'm still learning to program and i'm trying to add two arrays, A and B, while keeping track of carry. The arrays are all of `SIZE = 20` and look like this: `A = {0,0,..,n}`
My code below does not seem to work and I cannot for the life of me find out what the error is. For example, if I add
           `A ={0,0,0...,1,2,3}` as an array and
          `B ={0,0,0,...,7,8,9}` as an array I get `802` instead of `912.`
 Code:

```
    int index = SIZE -1; 
    int[] newBI = new int[SIZE]
    while(index >=0)
    {   
        int carry = 0; 
        int sum = A[index] + B[index] + carry;
        if(sum >=10) {
            carry = sum/10;
            sum = sum %10; 

        }
        newBI[index] = sum; 
        index--; 
    }
    return newBI; 
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Every time you start your while loop, you initialise `carry` to 0 and then add it to the sum. You then don't do anything with the `carry` that you calculate in the `if` statement. (Chances are you want to declare `carry` outside the loop.)

Comment: Does your task require you to account for the fact that the array could end on the left side with another carry, thus requiring one more length than the two originals? eg: {9,9,9} + {9,9,9} = {1,9,9,8}

Comment: make sure  you are not  doing it from left-to-right in the program and  your calculation  from right-to-left.

Comment: @MichaelBerry he also needs  an `else`,  if there is not `carry` to set it to `0` .

Comment: Technically, neither `if` nor `else` is needed. If both are excluded, the integer operations will take care of themselves. Of the calculated sum, `carry = sum / 10` is always the left digit or zero, and `sum = sum % 10` is always the right digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been noted in the comments, you need to remember the value of `carry` from one digit to the next. Also, it's important to clear the `carry` when there's no digit overflow. Finally, if `carry` is set when the loop ends then the sum is too large to fit in the array.

```
static int[] sum(int[] A, int[] B)
{
  int index = SIZE -1; 
  int[] newBI = new int[SIZE];
  int carry = 0;
  while(index >=0)
  {   
      int sum = A[index] + B[index] + carry;
      if(sum >= 10) {
          carry = sum/10;
          sum = sum %10; 
      }
      else
      {
        // important to clear the carry
        carry = 0;
      }
      newBI[index] = sum; 
      index--; 
  }
  if(carry == 1)
  {
    throw new ArithmeticException();
  }
  return newBI; 
}
```